# Xmpullparser Android nested tag

Tags: android, android-xmlpullparser

I have problem with parsing my xml document, I need take values from section: coordinates. There is not problem with parsing  and  section.

Below there is my xml document and part of code. Any sugestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
        <Placemark id="placemark1">
            <name>test_name</name>
            <description>geom_test</description>
            <point>
                <coordinates>40.751816, -73.959119</coordinates>
            </point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark id="placemark2">
            <name>test_name1</name>
            <description>geom_test</description>
            <point>
                <coordinates>40.751816, -73.959119</coordinates>
            </point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Code:

```
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        continue;
    }
    String name = parser.getName();
    if (name.equals("Placemark")) {
        String id = null, date = null, pob = null;
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
            }
            name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("name")) {
                id = readText(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("description")) {
                date = readText(parser);
            } else if (name.equals("point")) {
                parser.nextTag();
            } else if (name.equals("coordinates")) {
                pob = readText(parser);
            }
        }
        myDbHelper.insertData(id, date, pob);
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that nextTag() goes to coordinates tag directly and the next() call gives you a end tag.

So, you should get the text after call nextTag or directly call next and reenter in the while loop (with next you are "opening" coordinates tag and not "inside").

Option1 nextTag for next:

```
} else if (name.equals("point")) {
    parser.next();
}
```

Option 2 is to call getText after getNextTag:

```
} else if (name.equals("point")) {
    parser.nextTag();
    if (parser.getName().equals("coordinates")) {
        pob = parser.nextText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, It's working, how can I seperate into two tables values from coordinates?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If is working please select as correct answer!!

Comment: I mean substring from parsing values, in coordinates there are 2 values. How to prepare parsing part of all?

Comment: If you want to separate the coordinates you could do a pob.split(",") which will return a String array with both values